# Repeating integers question

Tags: combinatorics

A repeating integer is one in which a sequence of digits occurs two or more times to make
the entire number. The 4-digit number 4242 is a repeating integer. How many numbers are
six-digit repeating integers?

I've tried some casework but I can't just get to the right answer
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

There are three types:

Type 1: aaaaaa

Type 2: ababab

Type 3: abcabc

Note that left most digit should be nonzero, other digits have no restriction.

Now count how many in each type and add them up.

EDIT: Perhaps this is obvious. But you have to check that these 3 types cover all possibilities.

Comment: If you read the OP's question, they have *already tried by cases*. They're having trouble with this.

Comment: @Myridium: This shows some help in the casework.  I think it is a good hint.

Comment: I like to see hints, but I think you should also note that these cases can overlap, albeit very little.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea to try by cases is a good one. In all cases, we must be careful with the digit $0$ because it can't be the leading digit.

#### Case 1: 1 digit repeated

We can have digits 1 through 9 which are repeated. This gives us 9 possibilities.

#### Case 2: 2 digits repeated

Our two digits are an ordered pair $(d_1,d_2)$ with $10\cdot 10$ possibilities including $0$. Zero must be treated specially, though, because it can't be the leading digit. Let's remove the possibilities of the form $(0,d_2)$ which result in this problem. There are $10$ of them, so we're left with $9 \cdot 10$ possibilities. We've already counted those cases where $d_1 = d_2$ though, so let's remove those too. There are only $9$ of them since we've removed $(0,0)$ already.

$2$ distinct digits makes for a total possible $9^2$ possibilities.

#### Case 3: 3 digits repeated

Things get sticky here, because it's not obvious that we couldn't choose $(d_1, d_2, d_3)$ to get something which is the same as the $2$ digits repeated case. However, we won't run into this problem (I think because $2$ and $3$ are coprime). Suppose they do overlap:

$$d_1 d_2 d_3 d_1 d_2 d_3 = d_4 d_5 d_4 d_5 d_4 d_5$$
This results in $d_1 = d_4 = d_5$ meaning that it only occurs when all digits are the same. So we can rest assured that it is only necessary to remove cases where $d_1 = d_2 = d_3$.

Like the $2$ digit case, we take all possible tuples $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ to be $10^3$ then remove $10^2$ of them because they result in a leading $0$. We are left with $ 9 \cdot 10^2$. We then remove the cases where all numerals are the same-- there are $9$ of these since we've already removed $(0,0,0)$.

Hence we have $9 \cdot (10^2 - 1)$ combinations with three digits not already accounted for.

### Adding them up

$$9 + 9^2 + 9(10^2 - 1) = 9(1 + (10^2 - 1) + 9) = 9(10^2 + 9) = 981$$

Comment: Suppose the first digit is $9$, you are left with digits $0\;through\;8$ for the next two, how will you get $(10^2-1)$ ways for them ?

Comment: @trueblueanil - The digits are chosen independently. If the first digit is $9$, we may choose $0 \; through \; 9$ for the next two digits as well. But we must ensure that they're not both $9$, as the combination $(9,9,9)$ is already accounted for.

Comment: But if the subsequences of $3$ don't have $3$ *distinct* digits, they can overlap with subsequences of $2$.

Comment: @trueblueanil - Have you read my answer...? I explicitly show that it will not happen unless all digits are the same. Also please see my comment on your answer.

Comment: @trueblueanil - I think your answer was good. You might consider reinstating it with the missing possibilities.

Comment: I have done so, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We need to ensure that the first digit $\neq 0$ and subsequences repeat

$a|a|a|a|a|a: 9\;$

$ab|ab|ab: 9\cdot9 = 81$

$aab|aab,\quad aba|aba,\quad abb|abb: 9(1\cdot9 + 9\cdot1 + 9\cdot1) =243$

$abc|abc: 9\cdot9\cdot8 = 648,\; totalling\; \boxed{981}$